# Is there a way to search a menu bar in Gnome?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I want to search my menu bar, to easily find obscure menu items.

I know that the HUD (Heads Up Display) in Unity has this feature, however I am running Gnome 3 on Debian 7.

Is there a way to do this on my system?

Comment: so, did my answer solve the problem, or do you need additional help/tips/whatever?

Comment: @AlexejMagura No, Sorry, What I meant was searching the menus of a program not searching for the program itself.

Comment: oh, I don't know how I could have missed that...  I'll see if I can delete my answer then.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you try `mate-hud`.

https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/mate-hud

It is based on `Rofi` and works like a charm for me on Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no. The gnome shell doesn't include such characteristics as Unity. There were some projects like [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) to make this possible in any desktop environment but it's dead. There's also Conky and Gnome-do but it functionality can be lacking.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called "plotinus" that does just that: https://github.com/p-e-w/plotinus and it is designed to work with every GTK3+ application. 
I feel like it is still WIP.
I managed to make it work with gedit and nautilus but not easily.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Please review the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information regarding this. Thank you!